# How to update a value by 1 if the new value inserted into the database clashes with value in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to update the database of the sort order column to increase its value by one if the the new value inserted into the database clashes with the value that is already in the database. May I know how should I go about doing it? Please help! Thanks!
Below is my code (I am not sure whether am I on the right track):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sortorder FROM information ORDER BY id ASC;");
if($result >= 1 ){                     
    $i=1;

    while ($initialorder = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))    
    {
        $initialorder = $initialorder["sortorder"];                          
        if ($sortorder == $initialorder ){
          $result6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information 
               WHERE `sortorder` = '$sortorder'"); 

          $row6 = mysql_fetch_array($result6);        
          $removethis1 = $row6['id'];    
          $result7 = mysql_query("UPDATE information 
              SET `sortorder`= ((SELECT `sortorder` 
                  FROM (SELECT MAX(`sortorder`) AS 
                 '$initialorder' FROM information) AS '$initialorder') + 1) 
              WHERE id='$removethis1'");
    }                         

    $query = "INSERT INTO `information`                  
      (`id`,`page`,`description`,`status`,`sortorder`,`keyword`,`date_added`) 
       VALUES 
      ('$id','$title','$description','$status',
       '$sortorder','$keyword','$date_added')";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    header('Location: index.php?status=1&title='.$title);

    $i++;  }

    }
```

Comment: What should happen if you try to `set sortorder = 1` and `sortorder` values up to 10,000 are already taken? Whats the logic behind this `sortorder` column?

Comment: Are you trying to insert new 'information' (a 'page' in yet another cms, right?) or to reorder existing 'information' when user wants to change sortorder?

Comment: @OGHaza the logic behind sort order column is to arrange the order of the information displayed in the front-end page. Whenever the administrator add in new information and he/she entered "1" and the order number "1" is in the database under sortorder column, I want the newly entered value to take the "1" and the value in the database to add 1 to the max value of the sortorder column.

Comment: @shomeax I am trying to insert new information and reorder the existing'information' if the value entered in sort order field clashes with the value under sort order column in information table.

Comment: @user2946964, why can't the highest number be the row to show first? That way the sort order on old information never has to change

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO ON `information`
...
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  sortorder = '".$sortorder + 1." '
```